# No completions available, strange Eclipse behavior

Tags: java, eclipse, content-assist

I think I tried every suggested solution, but this Eclipse auto-complete problem is quite particular:

1. I launch Eclipse, content assist works fine;
2. I want to create a LineBorder in my Swing project;
3. I type `LineBorder panelBorder = new Li` and hit Ctrl+Space;
4. No popup appears and in the status bar it writes in red "No completion available";
5. I try Ctrl+Space on the elements where content assist worked fine 2 secs earlier, it doesn't work anymore.
6. I try the same thing on other project, on the same project after closing and reopening it, after cleaning it and content assist works just fine before I try using LineBorder constructor, then it crashes.

What I tried:

1. Reset to defaults in 'Preferences->Java->Editor->Content Assist->Advanced';
2. Check every single checkbox in the same menu;
3. Create a new workspace and try it there;
4. Delete .index files and 'savedIndexNames.txt' in .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core;
5. Check for the duplicate libraries.

What I didn't try is reinstalling Eclipse. The version I use is Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (Juno).

Nothing seems to work.

UPDATE:

Checked the logs as [iGili](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1499142/igili) suggested.
There are some exceptions raised at the time of failure:

```
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException: While executing the action, an exception occurred
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException: While executing the action, an exception occurred
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.codeassist.InternalCompletionProposal.findConstructorParameterNames(InternalCompletionProposal.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.codeassist.InternalCompletionProposal.findParameterNames(InternalCompletionProposal.java:1456)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.java.CompletionProposalLabelProvider.appendUnboundedParameterList(CompletionProposalLabelProvider.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.java.CompletionProposalLabelProvider.createMethodProposalLabel(CompletionProposalLabelProvider.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.java.CompletionProposalLabelProvider.createStyledLabel(CompletionProposalLabelProvider.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.LazyJavaCompletionProposal.computeDisplayString(LazyJavaCompletionProposal.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.LazyJavaCompletionProposal.getStyledDisplayString(LazyJavaCompletionProposal.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup.handleSetData(CompletionProposalPopup.java:841)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup.access$24(CompletionProposalPopup.java:831)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup$3.handleEvent(CompletionProposalPopup.java:593)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.checkData(Table.java:1166)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.wmNotifyChild(Table.java:6749)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.wmNotify(Control.java:5534)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.wmNotify(Composite.java:1896)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_NOTIFY(Control.java:5086)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4584)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1627)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2069)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProc(OS.java:2440)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.callWindowProc(Table.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.callWindowProc(Table.java:430)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
```

and it goes on, I don't know what is the convention for posting long stack traces

Comment: When I check on my Eclipse it works fine, I use the same Eclipse.
Does it happen only to this example or `CTRL + Space` doesn't work at all?

Comment: Ctrl+Space works pretty much everywhere before I try this example and doesn't work at all after it.

Comment: check this http://blog.rtwilson.com/how-to-solve-the-ctrl-space-auto-complete-not-working-problem-in-eclipse/

Comment: I don't think Ctrl+Space is assigned to some other task because in that case it wouldn't work at all. In my case it works again when I restart Eclipse/reopen the project/clean the project until I try to use autocomplete for the given example

Comment: I would suggest re-install Eclipse, I think is a quick way. Let me know if it solved the problem

Comment: Reinstalling didn't solve the problem, though I expected it to.

Comment: have u tried this: go to your workspace directory and go to .metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.jdt.core. Close Eclipse, rename that directory, and reopen the workspace ?

Comment: check in workspace/.metadata/.log or eclipse/configuration/<timestamp>.log for interesting exceptions. post here if there are any from the time that autocomplete crashed. you can also look at Window > Show View > PDE Runtime > Error Log when it happens.

Comment: @iGili There are indeed some interesting exceptions, I updated the post. As I mentioned there I don't know if I should post the whole stack trace or the part I find important when the stack trace is too long.

Comment: @knowbody I tried it now, no effect

Answer (score 80):

I had the same. Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced. Make sure "Java Proposals" checkbox is ticked at default content assist list (1st panel of the pop up).

By clicking "Restore Defaults" button at the bottom "Java Proposals" could be checked automatically.

Comment: This actually worked for me, but very strange that this option is disabled by default!

Answer (score 5):

Go back to the Advanced Content Assist preference page and Restore Defaults.  Close the dialog using the OK button.

Comment: That's exactly what I did multiple times. Doesn't help

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Actually I had the content assist pop up, but that was smaller than a couple of pixels.(Who shrunk this and why was it shrunk no idea whatsoever...)
But if you see something strange(in my case, that was the letters 'Rp', but I guess it can be anything) where normally the content assist should appear, try to expand it, and you might get it back. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

None of these answers helped me: Java Proposals was ticked, and restoring defaults didn't do anything. It started working only after I restarted Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced ( Java Proposals) need to be choosen.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to create a new workspace and copy all the projects to that workspace. The issue now only occurs on the previous workspace.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running into a known defect in 3.6. see [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=320167)

try to download a newer release- it is fixed since 3.7

**[edit]** I just realized that you've wrote 'Juno'- are you using the latest (4.2.2)?

Comment: I am using 4.2, I have reported the bug after failing to find a reasonable explanation

Comment: I was going to suggest exactly that

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the same problem in Juno switching workspace and then switching back. Other solutions didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but in only one particular file in my project (completion worked fine on other files). I'm also using Eclipse Juno.

I fixed the problem by removing some warnings due to unused imports in the file where completion failed... and it started working again!

Answer (score 0):

This checkbox "java proposals" will be ticked until I have failed and got "No completions available". After that, it will show as unticked the next time I am opening the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Go to 
Eclipse → Preferences → Java → Editor → Content Assist → Restore Defaults

and then
Project → Clean

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't expand sysout this morning. After a couple of wasted hours, I found that I was trying to put System.out.println() outside a method. When I did it inside a method, it all worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue just now with Eclipse version 2019-06 (4.12). For me a Project clean solved the problem.