# No completion available in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete

What causes strange Eclipse behavior that prevents to auto complete the code I typed by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>? And how to solve this issue?

Comment: Which editor are you using (Java, C, C++, JavaScript, XML, HMTL, .....)?

Comment: what is the status message coming in below status bar.

Comment: Look in `Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced` and see if there are any proposals actually enabled.

Comment: Preferences -> Java\Editor\Content Assist\Advanced\ Java Proposal to be specific.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No completions available, strange Eclipse behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15728776/no-completions-available-strange-eclipse-behavior)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same. Windows-->Preferences --> Java --> Editor --> Content Assist --> Advanced. Make sure -Java Proposals- is ticked.

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15728776/no-completions-available-strange-eclipse-behavior).

Answer (score 2):

To be precise this steps i usually take when such kind of bug come in my eclipse `kepler,juno,gallileo`(Tested)

1. **New WorkSpace**

   Create a totally new workspace and import your existing project using import option general "import exisiting one".
2. **Content Assist setup**

   Go to `Preferences>Java>Editor>Content Assist>Advanced`. Make sure “Other Java Proposals” is checked. Saying configure the behavious of program.
3. **No Overriding of ctrl+space**

   Make sure (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>) combination key is not overridden by other application. Like a snapshot taker at my side did it.

Comment: For CDT/C++ I went to the Content Assist settings->Advanced for C/C++ and selected "Parsing-based proposals" and "Word proposals". The problem was driving me crazy. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by re-running the indexer, even though I did not add a new file.